# How to add a classmethod in Python dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, lazy-evaluation, class-method

I'm using Python 3.
I know about the @classmethod decorator. Also, I know that classmethods can be called from instances.

```
class HappyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def say_hello():
        print('hello')
HappyClass.say_hello() # hello
HappyClass().say_hello() # hello
```

However, I don't seem to be able to create class methods dynamically AND let them be called from instances. Let's say I want something like

```
class SadClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # create a class method say_dynamic

SadClass.say_dynamic() # prints "dynamic!"
SadClass().say_dynamic() # prints "dynamic!"
```

I've played with `cls.__dict__` (which produces exceptions), and with `setattr(cls, 'say_dynamic', blahblah)` (which only makes the thingie callable from the class and not the instance).

If you ask me why, I wanted to make a lazy class property. But it cannot be called from instances.

```
@classmethod
def search_url(cls):
    if  hasattr(cls, '_search_url'):
        setattr(cls, '_search_url', reverse('%s-search' % cls._meta.model_name))
    return cls._search_url
```

Maybe because the property hasn't been called from the class yet...

In summary, I want to add a **lazy**, **class** method that can **be called from the instance**... Can this be achieved in an elegant (nottoomanylines) way?

Any thoughts?

**How I achieved it**

Sorry, my examples were very bad ones :\

Anyway, in the end I did it like this...

```
@classmethod
def search_url(cls):
    if not hasattr(cls, '_search_url'):
        setattr(cls, '_search_url', reverse('%s-search' % cls._meta.model_name))
    return cls._search_url
```

And the `setattr` does work, but I had made a mistake when testing it...

Comment: Why the `setattr` with a constant 2nd argument? You could as well write `cls._search_url = reverse(...)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How I achieved it:

```
@classmethod
def search_url(cls):
    if not hasattr(cls, '_search_url'):
        setattr(cls, '_search_url', reverse('%s-search' % cls._meta.model_name))
    return cls._search_url
```

Answer (score 18):

You can add a function to a class at any point, a practice known as monkey-patching:

```
class SadClass:
    pass

@classmethod
def say_dynamic(cls):
    print('hello')
SadClass.say_dynamic = say_dynamic

>>> SadClass.say_dynamic()
hello
>>> SadClass().say_dynamic()
hello
```

Note that you are using the `classmethod` decorator, but your function accepts no arguments, which indicates that it's designed to be a *static* method. Did you mean to use `staticmethod` instead?

Comment: Is it okay if you use @classmethod decorator outside of class? The code works, but I worry if is this a really pythonic way to solve the problem.

Comment: @AlexeiMarinichenko It's ok to use `@classmethod` outside of a class if you plan to attach the resulting function object to a class. Another matter is whether you need such monkey-patching in the first place. (You almost never do.)

Answer (score 11):

If you want to create class methods, do not create them in the `__init__` function as it is then recreated for each instance creation. However, following works:

```
class SadClass(object):
    pass

def say_dynamic(cls):
    print("dynamic")

SadClass.say_dynamic = classmethod(say_dynamic)
# or 
setattr(SadClass, 'say_dynamic', classmethod(say_dynamic))

SadClass.say_dynamic() # prints "dynamic!"
SadClass().say_dynamic() # prints "dynamic!"
```

Of course, in the `__init__` method the `self` argument is an instance, and not the class: to put the method in the class there, you can hack something like

```
class SadClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        @classmethod
        def say_dynamic(cls):
            print("dynamic!")

        setattr(self.__class__, 'say_dynamic', say_dynamic)
```

But it will again reset the method for each instance creation, possibly needlessly. And notice that your code most probably fails because you are calling the `SadClass.say_dynamic()` before any instances are created, and thus before the class method is injected.

Also, notice that a `classmethod` gets the implicit class argument `cls`; if you do want your function to be called without any arguments, use the `staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: `self` should be `cls` in the first part of your example.

Comment: You're right, writing it inside init would make kind of put extra work unnecessarily. My example was bad, but I actually *did* need the cls argument in real life. Sorry about that >.<

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you can just use an instance attribute to hold a function:

```
>>> class Test:
...    pass
... 
>>> t=Test()
>>> t.monkey_patch=lambda s: print(s)
>>> t.monkey_patch('Hello from the monkey patch')
Hello from the monkey patch
```